# Convex hull that follows irregular points distribution

Tags: postgis, saga, linux, convex-hull, bash

Based on an irregular distribution of points (longitude,latitude), I obtained the convex hull below (I use saga_cmd with polygon convexity in 1). Would you have a way to create a convex hull that closely follows this irregular shape using one-liner commands or similar? I call commands from a bash terminal in Linux.

[image]

Comment: there are concave hulls as well, an implementation exists in postgis, st_concave_hull

Comment: @ElioDiaz using `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" tmp.shp tmp.gmt -a_srs EPSG:4326 -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_AsBinary(ST_ConcaveHull(geometry,0.90))"` produces `no such column: geometry`. Without the word geometry, it only gives the DBF and PRJ files from the SHP file (ie. the SHP and SHX files are missing). My input is a two-columns GMT file.

Comment: i guess you are missing "select ... from table_name"

Comment: ogr2ogr -f GPKG tmp.gpkg puntos_monitoreo_2020_2021.gpkg -nln concava  -dialect sqlite -sql "select 'a', ST_ConcaveHull(st_collect(geometry),0.9) from puntos_monitoreo_2020_2021"

Comment: i used the code above for some points, you were very close, just missing the `st_collect(geometry)` (because in your case you have points and cannot make a hull on a single point, so you have to collect the layer) and `from table_name`; you get the table name with `ogrinfo tmp.gmt` then it will print the layer name like: `1. layer_name (Point)`

Comment: @ElioDiaz lo maximo! esta pensando ahorita...

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Comment: it is still working on the file (256608 points)... it goes 20 min already... does it take so long?

Comment: It is an expensive algorithm indeed, if you relax the threshold it will do it faster.

Comment: for ~20k points it took me 47 secs at 0.99 and 54 secs at 0.8

Comment: already 30 min and nothing, should I stop it?

Comment: Yes I guess you should test it on a subset first

Comment: if you have a fid field, pass "where fid < 1000" to the query

Comment: @ElioDiaz you were right! 1 sec and it is ready! thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PostGIS `ST_ConcaveHull`you may get the envelope to follow more closely the irregular shape, as stated in your post;

`ogr2ogr -f GPKG concave.gpkg points.gpkg -nln concave_layer -dialect sqlite -sql "select 'a', ST_ConcaveHull(st_collect(geometry),0.9) from points_layer"`

A few remarks:

1. You are using a point layer, so if you call `st_concave_hull` directly on your geometry it will try to make a polygon for each point, which will return empty geometries, so first we call `st_collect(geometry)`;
2. The layer name in the sql query can be retrieved with `ogrinfo file.gpkg`, it is often not the same name as the layer.
3. For some functions to work in ogr2ogr you need a non-geometry field, that's why I passed `'a'` to the command, here it works without it.
4. It is an expensive algorithm, to test it you may use a subset of your layer passing `where fid < 1000` to the query